# Scikit-Learn Training Job Save Model and Train/Val/Test Sets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to create a Scikit-learn Training Job that fits and saves a model and saves its train/val/test dataset split.
Is it possible to create an Estimator that saves a model's artifacts and its train/val/test artifacts? Could all the artifacts be used downstream in a training pipeline?

I opened a more complete question in the AWS Sagemaker Github Discussion board (https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/discussions/3848).

I imagine it's not possible to save additional artifacts besides the model as in a simpler problem, like saving model metrics, I couldn't find a solution that writes the metrics to a json file. The only existing solutions use regex matching on job logs to capture metrics.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a custom training script that saves any other artifacts you need to other files. I would utilize Boto3 as a client to save any custom metrics you need that are not saved out of box to S3 or the location of your choice.